# CORS issue when adding log4net config

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, log4net, owin-middleware

**Context:**

I have a simple Web API project with a controller and an action.
In the header of each request, I add an authorization token.
Everything work as expected. I can request a token based on some credentials, and use it to make HTTP requests successfully.

**Problem:**
When I add the following in the web.config:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <file value="logfile.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date: %-5level – %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
```

I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4042/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

If I remove the configuration for log4net everything works as expected.

**Note:** I do not have any setting in web.config that adds headers in a request.

**Startup.cs** is the only point in the project were I specify:

> app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

**Question:** How does the log4net configuration relate to preflight requests?
(based on my limited knowledge about the ASP.NET framework I would say it is non-sense). Is there a subtlety that am I missing?

Comment: My guess is that the log4net config is causing an exception, which is resulting in a 500 response that does not have the CORS header. Find out what the exception is.

Comment: Your `log4net` tag isn't closed, is that a typo?

Comment: @stuartd, yes it's a copy-paste mistake. I have it in my code. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the webconfig of my project and there is a part from a working `web.config`

```
   <configSections> 
         <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" /> 
       </configSections> 
       <log4net> 
         <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender"> 
          ...
        </log4net>
```

Maybe you missed `configSection`?

Comment: Thank you. Thant was the problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

use an external setting file for avoiding the problem :

At startup, call:

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

In your Web.config, specify log4net.Config in appSettings:

```
<add key="log4net.Config" value="Log.config" />
```

In the Log.config file put your configuration  :

```
<log4net>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <file value="logfile.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date: %-5level – %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
</root>
<log4net>
```